# how to make slide toggle function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make slide toggle function in angular .but did not get make perfect as we do in jquery see example .Panel come in slide down and hide in slide up .can we make in angular js
Demo 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Actually In my header there is **search** button (left side) using that I need to show toggle slide  button same animation as above .can we do in angular here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/wONbjeisEZtr7ffCmb15?p=preview

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.displaySearchBar=false;
  $scope.toggleSearch = function(){
    $scope.displaySearchBar= !$scope.displaySearchBar;
  }
})
```

In my demo it is coming from top .I need it open like as in w3 school example

Comment: put your seach button css under ion content . As Header in Ionic has fixed height and if you are going to put in header then will always see it sliding from top untill you did not make changes to default header Ionic css. So put content to toggle in ion content part. And for animations you can use ng animate .

Comment: could you please plunker ?

Comment: Ok take a look , http://plnkr.co/edit/B81diqR8N9yIqM2dl2Kg?p=preview . Just a demo

Comment: it is not same as w3 scroll example it is not slidding while when user press search

Comment: @PallaviSharma did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `z-index` for search bar, You need to remove it. Currently you are using `z-index` that is showing search bar on the top of the header while animating. Removing `z-index` will show you effect like w3 schools site.

**CSS**

```
.searchclass {
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 0 !important;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   /* z-index: 999; */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ARZwX3jFvg80NFvn4Pmh?p=preview)

Comment: @Pallavi Sharma does it helped you?